# LateX parts in article form and report form

Tags: latex

I am trying to divide my document into parts using `\part{}`. I am currently using 'article' as document class and when I add a part it looks like this:

[image: Part in Article document class]

However, I really like how the part is in the report document class:

[image: Part in Report document class]

Is there a way I can recreate the same design for the part in Report class and use in in my Article class document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look into `report.cls` and transplant the following definitions for the part page to your article:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\part{%
%  \if@openright
%    \cleardoublepage
%  \else
    \clearpage
%  \fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}

\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
       \huge\bfseries \partname\nobreakspace\thepart
       \par
       \vskip 20\p@
     \fi
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
    
\def\@spart#1{%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #1\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

test

\part{part name}
\section{title}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer it worked out just fine! I just have a similar question, imagine that now my document class is Report and would like to define the Report Chapter as an Article Section, the Report Section as an Article Subsection, and so on. How would I do that? Again looking at the .cls file?

Comment: @gapansi99  Make your life not unnecessarily complicate. If you have the structure of one class, then use this class